# Window partition in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, window, postgresql-8.4

In the below query I am trying to use the partition on the field product_id and order it by the week_end date. My question is do we need to use or rank() or some aggregate function in order to partition by a particular column. Because the below query fails if I dont use the rank() function, but I dont need the rank in my output. Is there any way to avoid the aggregate function and still use partition. Thanks!

```
 select c.week_end,a.product_id,b.metric_id,c."week_value",c."13week_value",c."52week_value",rank() over(partition by a.product_id order by c.week_end) from 
    Product_t a,metric_t b, vin_example_unpivot c where  
    c.prod_nm = a.product_nm and
    c."Metric" = b.metric_code
```

Comment: It fails because the partition by of an analytic function is meant to tell the window function (rank in your case) when to restart. Without the window function, you're giving an instruction to something that doesn't exist, which doesn't make sense. What are you trying to do?

Comment: What are you trying to "partition by product_id and order by week"?  Can you provide sample data and desired results?

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to sort the results by product id and the end date?

```
select c.week_end, a.product_id, b.metric_id, c."week_value", c."13week_value", c."52week_value"
from vin_example_unpivot c join
     Product_t a
     on c.prod_nm = a.product_nm  join
     metric_t b
     on c."Metric" = b.metric_code
order by product_id, week_end;
```

Note that I also fixed the joins to use proper join syntax.